# Vim with phpactor: Can we configure phpactor to find classes on old non psr code base

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, legacy-code

I'm working on supporting an old code base, and recently installed phpactor in my vim.  Unfortunately phpactor just can't seem to find classes that exist, but in non psr way.

I've worked with standalone code analyzers that often come with a configuration file I can use to hint-my-way to getting the number of "can't find xyz class" types of warnings down to a reasonable minimum.

Unfortunately phpactor doesn't like all these non compliant classes, and in this project it's rare for me to have a php file open that doesn't have a mini phpactor sub-window complaining about classes not found.

I like the idea of phpactor, and it really seems to work great for psr compliant code bases, but:

Is there a trick to clue in phpactor about specific files or classes?

Comment: What does this have to do with Vim? Isn't Phpactor is a standalone program that you are supposed to configure [separately](https://phpactor.readthedocs.io/en/master/usage/configuration.html).